# SQLAlchemy - Changing from useList=False to useList=True

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

If I change a relationship from `useList=False` to `useList=True` - do all the legacy relationships that have already been written to the DB still return a scalar object value? Or as soon as I change the relationship, any code reference will start returning a list?

Some relationship like
`User.Post`

Do I need to write a script or something to update all the legacy relationships? Or check in code on read of the relationship?

Comment: SQLAlchemy relationships exist only at the Python level. Changing `uselist` should not require any database changes, because the database only knows about foreign keys.